# Sort wp post title with alphabetically and numerically?

Tags: posts, sort

Is there any possible way to sort a new Wordpress post query by the title, but numerically instead of alphabetically?

I have some titles that have a lot of the same name alphabetically, then have a number afterwards, so of course for example Wordpress is putting `title12` ahead of `title1`.

```
$args = array( 'orderby'=> 'title', 'order' => 'ASC', ); $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I know we have this functionality to sort titles in ascending order but it does not sort titles like that:- Title 1 Title 2

Please let me know if we any work around using wp query ? Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: are you asking how to do a natural sort, aka 1,2,3,...,9,10 rather than 1,10,2,3,30,31 etc?

Comment: Could you provide example of titles and wanted/actual sort orders?

Comment: I think I can do this and I am curious enough in a sort of "code golf" kind of way :) , but I don't have time right now. I will try to check back in later.

Answer (score 2):

Well, technically what WP is doing is correct. 
You can either rename your titles using prefixed 0's.

```
Title 001
Title 012
```

Otherwise

You can use sorting using the publish date

Or you can use an order meta field and sort on that one using `wp_query`

Comment: +1. Better to use meta-data in the post, to store variables like this, than to go with Ugly post title formats, such as Some Title 001, just for the sake of organization. 

Using meta-data, you can retain all the flexibility, without compromising aesthetics.

Comment: I agree Hybrid, that would be my choice aswell.

Answer (score 0):

Your titles aren't numbers. You can't sort numerically if you don't have numbers. Where does "T" go in a numeric sequence?

However, if you have a consistent pattern that you can leverage to break apart the title-- I used a space character and assumed a pattern like "Title" + space + "number"-- you can do something like this:

```
function numeric_sort_title_field($fields) {
  remove_filter('posts_fields','numeric_sort_title_field');
  global $wpdb;
  $fields .= ', ';
  $fields .= 'REVERSE(';
    $fields .= 'LEFT(';
      $fields .= "REVERSE({$wpdb->posts}.post_title),";
      $fields .= "LOCATE(' ',REVERSE({$wpdb->posts}.post_title))";
    $fields .= ')';
  $fields .= ') + 0';
  $fields .= ' AS number';

  $fields .= ', ';
  $fields .= 'REVERSE(';
    $fields .= 'LEFT(';
      $fields .= "REVERSE({$wpdb->posts}.post_title),";
      $fields .= "LENGTH({$wpdb->posts}.post_title) - LOCATE(' ',REVERSE({$wpdb->posts}.post_title))";
    $fields .= ')';
  $fields .= ') + 0';
  $fields .= ' AS title_text';

  return $fields;
}
add_filter('posts_fields','numeric_sort_title_field');

function numeric_sort_title($orderby) {
  remove_filter('posts_orderby','numeric_sort_title');
  $orderby = ' title_text, number';
  return $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','numeric_sort_title');

$q = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
  )
);
var_dump($q->request);
if ($q->have_posts()) {
  while ($q->have_posts()) {
    $q->the_post();
    the_title();
    echo '<br>';
  }
}
```

You should get posts sorted by the text portion of the title and then by the numeric portion.