# Sort Woocommerce Products with Numbered Titles Numerically

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, css

I have a woocommerce shop with many products all of which have numbered titles from 1-3000 and the problem is, the alphabetical sorting is leaving me with an order like this: 1, 10, 11, 12, 100 and so on rather than 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc

Would anyone be able to suggest some php which could solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect the sort is actually done in the database. There's a few ideas [on this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557172/mysql-order-by-sorting-alphanumeric-correctly) but none of them very good I don't think.

Comment: Your best bet might be to create a new order column where you pad all the numbers to four or five digits or spaces, and sort by that instead. That's not going to be trivial to set up and automatically maintain though, plus actually hooking into the sort code as well.

Comment: Actually we have a question about that too: [Sort wp post title with alphabetically and numerically?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143680/sort-wp-post-title-with-alphabetically-and-numerically). Whether that's a duplicate or not depends on how WooCommerce does its queries which I'm not 100%, but I'd guess are the same.